# HOWTO use freemarker tag library in jsp files?

Tags: java, struts2, freemarker, taglib

I wanted to know how, if possible, to use freemarker tag library in a jsp file. I am using the Struts2 framework. Currently I do not have the bandwidth to convert all the jsp files in my project in to ftl file, hence the conundrum.

I checked out http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#autoid_57 but it does not really say much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have been doing the same thing where I work and we've created a custom taglib with tags for each of the templates we've put into our JSPs.

For example:
We have productSpecs.ftl that is replacing some content on a product page.
We've created a taglib (named ftl) and are putting  in our JSPs.
We have done some Java magic so that we have a Java class for each tag in our taglib.  In other words, there's a class called ProductSpecs.java that basically just loads the ftl file by the same name and combines it with our JSON data and writes the output in html.

There's a little more work than what I've detailed above, but my point is that it's totally possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts 2 tag library is implemented in JSP tags, Velocity tags, and Freemarker tags.  The syntax is slightly different for each view layer technology, but it's all well documented.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/struts-tags.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Free marker template in place of standard struts2 template than i believe framework provides an extension to this.

FreeMarker tags are extensions of the generic [Struts Tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/struts-tags.html) provided by the framework. You can jump right in just by knowing the generic structure in which the tags can be accessed: `<@s.tag> ...</@s.tag>`, where tag is any of the tags supported by the framework.

For more details refer to the official doc.

[Freemarker-tags](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/freemarker-tags.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use FreeMarker directives (tags) in a JSP file (unless someone has written a JSP taglib for that, but I strongly doubt that). (FreeMarker templates can use JSP tags, with limitations, but that's not what you are asking.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the javadocs for this tag: http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/api/freemarker/ext/jsp/FreemarkerTag.html
But I really didn't find any examples using it. It should do the thing you're saying, I'm looking for the same thing.